# Nginx is not working with multiple domain when we trying to proxy pass each domain to ELB it only pass the content of 1 domain for both sites

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

#### Nginx is not working with multiple domain when we trying to proxy pass each domain to internal load balancer  ################################################################
    worker_processes  auto;
    events{
        worker_connections  1024;
        }

```
http{
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] - [$request_time] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent"';


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log error;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxxx.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/xxxxxx.com.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxxxx.com.error.log error;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://internal-ELB.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
               }
      }
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  yyyyy.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/yyyy.com.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/yyyy.com.error.log error;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://internal-BT-internal.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please edit your post so that it is readable.

Comment: What errors are you seeing on the error logs?

Comment: I did not get any error log in nginx , xxx.com is working fine but yyy.com domain URL is same but its content is same as xxx.com domain